# Usage of the word 'Cachet'

Tags: meaning, dictionaries

When I was about 10-15 years younger, I lived near a club named Cache. It was pronouced like 'sachet'.  I assumed at this time that this was the spelling of what is defined as 'Cachet'.  Also, I assumed that it meant to have the definition most closely to 'Cachet', but my understanding was a little different.  Much like the data storage definition of cache, I understood cachet to mean that you had a collection of respect or clout.

The definition in OED declares this is more of a state, and says nothing of amassed respect or clout.  Since, with the inclusion of ridiculous newly added words, I now question everything about the OED.

Am I right in thinking this about cachet, that it implies amassed respect or clout?  Or does it not have this sense, and is only really a state?

ADDENDUM: It should also be noted that this club was a West Indies Islands club. I don't know enough Spanish to know if Cache means the same as the English cachet. The definition I cited (not the computer data cache) is the sense I got of its use.

Comment: At the moment I am not sure what your question is. I'm confused about your mention of 'cache'. It is a different word with a different meaning and a different pronunciation from 'cachet'.  Which word are you asking about?  Which definition of cachet are you complaining about -- can you show us with a link? Thanks.

Comment: Where on earth did you get this 'data storage definition of cache'?

Comment: Easy chasly.  I'm not complaining in the least.  I cited a dissatisfaction with what was formerly an undisputed authority.  Chris Sunami seems to have understood my question, and the definition of cache I cited.  In fact, my question is not masked whatsoever.  Question marks will typically follow a question.  Simply, does the definition of cachet imply amassed respect or clout.  The lead-in is background on why I think this.  Not misleading at all.

Comment: The two last comments on Josh61's response were hidden; I jumped a little there.  Hopefully this all makes sense now.  I will add some extra notes to the original question.

Comment: In American English, "cache" and "cachet" are two entirely different things, with different pronunciations.  The fact that the word "cache" in Spanish would be pronounced like the word "cachet" in English does not make the two related.  Refer to an English dictionary and look up "cache" and "cachet".

Comment: Thank you hot licks, for directing me to look in the dictionary, which I stated above I'd already done. Let's not keep rehashing this.  Move on.

Answer (score 6):

The word *cachet* (pronounced ka-SHAY'), meaning having prestige or high status, is often misspelled, and also often confused with the word *cache* (KASH'), which is currently most familiar to many people as the word meaning persisted data storage of temporary assets by a computer internet browser (from its older meaning as a small, hidden storage space).

The two words are both French in origin, but their meaning is not related, so the happy thought that *cachet* is a *cache* of respect is not correct, etymologically speaking. With that said, the definition is not that far off --someone with *cachet* does in fact command respect, generally speaking.

As far as the club, I'd guess the owners meant "Cachet" but accidentally misspelled it "Cache."

Comment: It is entirely possible that the club owners intended the Spanish/English word "cache" (which would be pronounced ka-SHAY in Spanish), to mean "hiding place".  This would be a reasonable name for a small club.

Comment: Actually *cache* and *cachet* seem to be etymologically related. A *cachet* was originally a seal which got its name from a verb meaning *to press*, while a *cache* was a hiding place which got its name from the same verb, although in this case it possibly meant something more like *"to jam things together in a small space"*.

Comment: (And, in fact, the club owner may have been punning a bit, knowing that "cache" would be pronounced, roughly, "ka-SHAY" in Spanish, sounding like the French/English "cachet", so he got the double meaning of "hiding place" and "prestige".)

Answer (score 3):

Here are the definitions and differences between the two similar terms. Cachet means also "prestige" which is probably the 'respect' you are referring to:

[Cache vs cachet](http://grammarist.com/usage/cache-cachet/):

> - A ***cache*** is (1) a hiding place used for storing provisions or valuables, or (2) a concealed collection of valuable things. *The word also functions as a verb meaning to hide or store in a cache.*
> - ***Cachet*** refers to (1) a mark or indication of superior status, or (2) prestige. *The word is is usually a mass noun (meaning it is treated as a quantity and can’t be pluralized), but it’s a count noun in some rarer senses.*

Examples:

> - It was the single largest *cache of prehistoric watercraft*  ever discovered. [Wall Street Journal]
> - It might not have *the cachet of Tuscany*, but that may be why this region along the Adriatic is still able to offer wines at bargain deals. [Edmonton Journal]
> - After the bomber detonated his *cache of explosives*, two other militants stormed inside the hotel. [Scotsman]
> - Nordic crime fiction carries a more *respectable cachet* – justifiably or otherwise – than similar genre fiction produced in Britain or the US. [Independent]
> - The explosive detection dogs are the best way of detecting improvised explosive devices and Taliban *weapons caches*. [Canberra Times]
> - Beijing would love to wield the *cachet that American culture commands*, but experts say it can’t as long as its authoritarian leaders call the shots. [Los Angeles Times].

(grammarist.com)

Comment: I'm not really sure this answers the question. You just quoted the dictionary and gave a few examples which the OP could have done.  In fact the OP should have done their own research at least to this level before asking.

Comment: What I understand is that OP appears to be confused about the two terms, and about the usage of 'cachet'. My post clearly explains the difference between the two and offers clear usage example which are not easily found in dictionaries. You can CV if you think that OP should have done more research.

Comment: I don't believe in a CV without first asking for clarification. I did ask and I'm now waiting. If there is no response then I'll vote to close. The OP is already questioning the validity of the OED, why should they believe the Grammarist more than the OED?

Comment: I think OP may have misread or misunderstood those definitions. The source I cite is reliable despite your unfounded doubts. Are we here to help or just to make things difficult?

Comment: Well this is turning into a discussion but I think it may be worth it. I did not voice my doubts at all - I reflected the OP's doubts about dictionaries. If the OP misunderstood the definitions then we need to see the definitions the OP misunderstood and ask for reasons - then we'd have something to discuss. Otherwise we're just trying to club them into submission with even more definitions.

Comment: P.S. I've just seen Chris Sunami's answer and, in my opinion that does tackle the problem much more effectively and insightfully.